# Z3 - mkInt() vs mkIntConst()

Tags: java, z3

Are the following equivalent?

`mkInt(3)` and `(IntExpr) mkIntConst("3")`?

The second one isn't creating an integer constant named "3", right? What I want is creating a constant with numeric value 3, using `mkIntConst`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mkIntConst` *creates* a symbolic value with the given name. (So in your case, the variable is named `3`, it does *not* have the value 3.

`mkInt` creates a constant with that value.

So yeah, these are totally different.

See here: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classcom_1_1microsoft_1_1z3_1_1_context.html#a99be64ea1573a49e683067bf6023ffa4

If you want to create a symbolic value that has the value `3`, then create one with `mkIntConst` and then add an assertion to the solver indicating it is equal to `3`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I just used `toString()` operator on them and got to know the difference in representation as well. `mkIntConst("3")` displays `|3|` while `mkInt(3)` displays `3`.